# How does Cauchy-Schwarz imply Hölder inthe special case $p=q=2$?

Tags: lp-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

I've read in a few places that Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality for the inner product of $L^2$ is just Hölder's inequality for the special case $p=q=2$ but I think there is missing some (maybe trivial) step.

Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality for the inner product of $L^2$ gives 
$$\left\vert{\int_X f \overline{g} }\right\vert \leq \int_X|f|^2\int_X|g|^2$$
And triangle inequality for integrals gives
$$\left\vert{\int_X f \bar{g}}\right\vert \le \int_X \left\vert{f g}\right\vert $$
I don't see how to arrive to 
$$\int_X \left\vert{f g}\right\vert  \leq \int_X|f|^2\int_X|g|^2$$
from Cauchy-Schwarz's, I mean I would understand it if the triangle inequality were the other way round

Comment: $|fg|=|f|\,|g|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider C-S inequality for $|f|$ and $|g|$.

Comment: Of course, thanks!